# Activity becoming null

Tags: android, android-context

In my application `getActivity()` returns null sometimes and so app crashes. This occurs very rarely, but it is reproducible when app is kept in background for long time. I use `getActivity()` to get context at various places. Is there any other method to get context in application? Is there any standards suggested? Is it good to use application context everywhere?

Comment: Add a null pointer Check to avoid exception

Comment: share some code where you are trying to get context of Activity.. and also null pointer check..

Comment: You can get context using `getApplicationContext()`. However, before getting so, why not use a null check :

`If(null != getApplicationContext()){//Your_code}`

Comment: getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
public void run() {  ////  } });  I use getActivity() in cases like this. I avoided crash by adding null check. But in my app it is used several times. Can anyone please suggest any standards for getting application context in such cases.. Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you called getActivity() in your fragment. 
You should check method onDetach() after it getActivity will return null (your fragment is detached).
If your code is related to current activity of fragment it will be better to just skip any work after detach. If your code is "all app life" its better to use ApplicationContext
To use or not to user ApplicationContext is depends of your task and type of resouce.